# standard SQL/XML function?

Tags: xml, database, oracle11g, db2, sqlxml

I'm studying the SQL / XML standard.
but I'm very confused as to which functions provides the standard?
I would like a complete list of all functions that provides the standard, where can I find? on the internet I always find the main functions.
In addition to IBM and Oracle XML transformations using XSLTransform and XmlTransform, but what is the function introduced by the standard?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The part 14 of the [SQL standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL:2011) defines the XML data type and related functionality and is referred to as [SQL/XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL/XML) (XML-Related Specifications). You may directly get those standard documents from either ANSI or ISO, or try to use those documents, sometimes drafts of the final specification, that are available by database vendors or researchers. See the linked SQL/XML information on Wikipedia for some resources.

Note that the standard not only defines the names of those functions and procedures, but also their exact semantics and parameters. Many vendors follow the standard losely.